# Barcheck failed (Lilypond)

Tags: notation, lilypond

This piano excerpt is somewhere in movement two of "**Trio élégiaque No. 2 in D minor, Op.9 (Rachmaninoff, Sergei)**".

Listen here:

or here:

Here's a small portion (considered as fair use here) from a sheet of that excerpt.

[image]

I am trying to re-create this in LilyPond. But somehow this last `es'''2` doesn't show up in the right measure. It should start in the next measure.

I have inputted it as:

```
<< {

es'''2

} \\ {

r16

} \\ >>
```

See the current result:

[image]

Comment: Actually *barcheck failed* is a strong indication, that you got the meter wrong or had notes too few/too many within the bar. I fail to recognize, what videos could help here and suggest [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Trio_%C3%A9l%C3%A9giaque_No.2_in_D_minor%2C_Op.9_(Rachmaninoff%2C_Sergei)) instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The music is in 3/4, so the time signature in your LilyPond work is wrong.  Correct it and the software should render the Eb in the correct place.

Comment: I don't have the hardware available currently to test this, but I assume this to be correct. What code to insert exactly please?

Comment: \time 3/4, see http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/displaying-rhythms#time-signature